# Aws Ecs Fargate Auto Scaling Scale Down Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, autoscaling, aws-fargate

I have a Aws Ecs Service by Fargate. I made up to 100 and min 3 container running, but I have question. In scale down which container will die first as default? Can you give me some source url and how can I change and customize it?

Thank you

I need a policy and how I will attach to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is documented anywhere how ECS Autoscaling scale-in will determine which Fargate tasks to terminate. I think you should assume it is going to be fairly random.

If you need to protect specific task instances from termination, you can use [Task scale-in protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-scale-in-protection.html).